# Bypass Managed Router to allow External Access to Security System DVR

Tags: cisco, router, wide-area-network

I am attempting to allow access to a Security System DVR from outside our network, via IP. We currently have a managed Cisco router connecting to the outside world via a cable modem provided by our ISP. The Router currently prevents external connections from accessing the DVR. The company managing the router is willing to put a hole in the firewall to allow access to the DVR but are unable to do so for at least a month.

So my question is:

Is there any way I can bypass this managed router (at least temporarily) and connect the DVR directly to the outside world using another switch/router between the modem and managed router? If so, what would be the best method to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate what joeqwerty said, yes this can be done as he described.  Or you can place a 2nd router between the switch and DVR as you described.

IF you have traditional coax cams this is ok so long as you dont mind making your cameras available to everyone in the world.  DVR's are not known for their robust security features, and are generally easily exploitable.

HOWEVER if that DVR is connected to IP cameras then I can't stress enough NEVER, EVER should what you asked be done.  This is is the equivalent of leaving the the office unlocked at night with computers logged in.  It wouldn't take a semi-professional malicious actors more then a few minutes to exploit many DVR's and jump into your corporate network.

Frankly punching a hole in the firewall to allow outside access in isn't much better, your still enabling the world to potentially have access to your internal network via a DVR. If you setup an ACL for that "hole" in the firewall and only allow connections from specific IP's then its likely an acceptable risk.

There are a few ways you could accomplish this and maintain a generally accepted best security practices posture.

BEST OPTION
1. Setup a remote VPN to allow authenticated access to your internal network,  This could be used for more then just reviewing the cameras.  Have you every wished you could RDP into your computer to get the grocery list you saved on your desktop ;).  Cisco ASA's have this ability although it may require an additional license.  You could also standup an openVPN server for little to no cost if thats of interest. (but that's another post altogether)

Better Option
2. Create a separate subnet for the DVR and IP cameras, if applicable. (you could either use another port on the Cisco for it, or use a VLAN if your infrastructure supports it).  Then create the "hole" in your firewall for access to that subnet, that way someone can't jump into your corporate network from the DVR.

Final Note: I am a security professional, so if I sound paranoid, its unfortunate that Ive seen to much reality. If your curious just how insecure a DVR can be, check out the following article.

http://www.kerneronsec.com/2016/02/remote-code-execution-in-cctv-dvrs-of.html

Comment: The system is a traditional COAX camera to DVR setup and allowing external users access to the cameras isn't really a concern. I do currently have a VPN set up on the network, however, using the VPN isn't an option as the system is primarily accessed by users via a mobile app that does not support a VPN configuration. As @joeqwerty suggested, I have connected the Router and DVR to a switch connecting to the Modem. If I am not concerned with limiting access to the DVR would it be safer to keep this as a permanent configuration rather than opening up the router?

Comment: Knowing how insecure DVR's can be I personally I would go with either the separate router as you have currently or if you don't want the the extra hardware (and additional single point of failure -the switch) then I'd either create a VLAN or separate network segment on the Cisco for the DVR node.  So long as the Cisco is properly configured this would be equally secure.  The moral of the story is you don't want the dvr to be on the corporate LAN if its exposure to the outside world is not secured.  Let me know if you have any more questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this? Sure. Is it a good idea? Probably not.

Get a switch. Connect the internal (LAN) port of the modem to the switch. Connect the external (WAN) port of the router to the switch. Connect the DVR to the switch. Assign a publicly routable ip address to the DVR.